# como dar altura fija a un td sin importar la altura de la tabla en html?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, html-tabla

tengo una tabla con una altura de 350px pero quiero que la altura de los td o bueno algunas filas sean fijas ya que me esta poniendo un alt relativo a todo las filas quiero que los td tengan una altura de un 25px

```
 <table border="1" style="height: 350px; table-layout: fixed; padding: 0; margin: 0;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr style="height: 0;">
            <td rowspan="2" style="">28. Carta de Porte No</td>
            <td rowspan="2" style="width: 40%!important; height: 20px!important; overflow: hidden;">29. Descripción de las Mercancías</td>
            <td rowspan="2" style="">30. Cantidad de los bultos</td>
            <td rowspan="2" style="">31. Clase y marca de los bultos</td>
            <td colspan="2" style="">32. Peso en Kilogramos</td>
            <td rowspan="2" style="">33. Volumen en m3 u otra unidad de medid</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="height: 0;">
            <td style="height: 0;">Bruto</td>
            <td style="height: 0;">Neto</td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
                <td style="border-bottom: 0; border-top: 0;">
                    hshshshs
                </td>
                <td style="width: 40%; border-bottom: 0; border-top: 0; text-align: center;">
                    <p>jsjjjjjjjjjjjsjsjsjsj</p>
                </td>
                <td style="border-bottom: 0; border-top: 0;text-align: center;">saaaaaaaaasasasasasa</td>
                <td style="border-bottom: 0; border-top: 0;text-align: center;">saaaaaaaaaaaaaassaas</td>
                <td style="border-bottom: 0; border-top: 0;text-align: center;">saaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
                <td style="border-bottom: 0; border-top: 0;text-align: center;">saaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
                <td style="border-bottom: 0; border-top: 0;text-align: center;">asssssssssssssssssss</td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
            <!--<td colspan="3">34. Precio de las Mercancías (INCOTERMS 2010) y tipo de moneda<br>CPT TULCAN USD 14.285,33</td>-->
            <td colspan="3" style="border:inset;">34. Precio de las Mercancías (INCOTERMS 2010) y tipo de moneda<br>saaaaaaaassasa</td>
            <td style="border:inset;text-align: center;">TOTAL</td>
            <td style="border:inset;text-align: center;">sddsdsdsdsdsds</td>
            <td style="border:inset;text-align: center;">saaaaaaaa</td>
            <td style="border:inset;text-align: center;">assssssssssss</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías intentar definir la misma altura para la primer celda de cada fila. Por ejemplo:

```
<td style="height:15px;">160 </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

¿Cómo es posible que hablemos sobre HTML5 y usemos estilos en línea?

Además, ¿cómo se obtiene una altura de 350px si las `td` van a tener una altura de 25px? Es mejor usar márgenes verticales o el tag `tbody`.

Tenga mucho cuidado porque los textos largos (sin espacios) afectan los anchos, mientras que el texto de varias líneas afecta las alturas.

Su archivo debería verse así:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Tabla</title>
  <style>
    table{table-layout:fixed;padding:0;margin:0;border-spacing:0}
    table,td{border:1px solid black}
    td{height:25px}
    .centert{text-align:center}
    .topbot{border-bottom:0;border-top:0}
    .wi40{width:40%}
  </style>
</head>

<body>
<table><!-- height:350px ?? -->
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">28. Carta de Porte No</td>
    <td rowspan="2">29. Descripción de las Mercancías</td>
    <td rowspan="2">30. Cantidad de los bultos</td>
    <td rowspan="2">31. Clase y marca de los bultos</td>
    <td colspan="2">32. Peso en Kilogramos</td>
    <td rowspan="2">33. Volumen en m3 u otra unidad de medid</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bruto</td>
    <td>Neto</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="topbot">hshshshs</td>
    <td class="centert topbot wi40">jsjjjjjjjjjjjsjsjsjsj</td>
    <td class="centert topbot">saaaaaaaaasasasasasa</td>
    <td class="centert topbot">saaaaaaaaaaaaaassaas</td>
    <td class="centert topbot">saaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
    <td class="centert topbot">saaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
    <td class="centert topbot">asssssssssssssssssss</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <!--<td colspan="3">34. Precio de las Mercancías (INCOTERMS 2010) y tipo de moneda<br>CPT TULCAN USD 14.285,33</td>-->
    <td colspan="3">34. Precio de las Mercancías (INCOTERMS 2010) y tipo de moneda<br>saaaaaaaassasa</td>
    <td class="centert">TOTAL</td>
    <td class="centert">sddsdsdsdsdsds</td>
    <td class="centert">saaaaaaaa</td>
    <td class="centert">assssssssssss</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

([**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/5qxfmps9/))

Lo siento pero solo hablo italiano y utilicé el traductor de Google :)